# How to test functions of my typescript package which facilitate communication between an iframe and its parent?

Tags: typescript, dom, iframe, jestjs, package

I've written a TypeScript package to facilitate communication between an iframe and its parent. For example, it includes a 'close' function. If the guest app calls this function, it will send a close message via post message to its host. Then, the host could decide how to handle the request to close.

Now, I want to write tests for my package using Jest. The problem here is that I don't know how to mount, implement, or even mock the iframe and its parent, and then call the desired functions to assert their effects.

In fact, I'm unsure how to create a suitable test bed for this scenario.

I used 'jsdom' as my testing environment and attempted to create an iframe HTML element. I then appended it to the document.body.

However, upon logging the children of my document, I noticed that nothing was appended. I'm unsure if my solution is suitable or not.

```
const guest = document.createElement('iframe');

it('sample test scenario', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(guest);
  console.log(document.body.children);
});
```

and here is the result in of the jest in the terminal:

```
 console.log
    HTMLCollection {}
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me find a good source to learn what I'm looking for and give me an idea to solve this problem.

Thank you.